External links Umbraco 13
I want to have some custom pages outside the CMS in my Umbraco website.
I'm using Umbraco 13
I want to create a folder on the ftp: /my-custom-pages
and to be able to navigate to this folder
but I'm getting page not found
in the past (previous versions) I could do it through the web.config
How do I do it in Umbraco 13 ?
Thanks

This is the expected behaviour as Umbraco is looking for a template and a document type to return the content page, and it seems like you don't have them.
There is more than one way to do the redirects on Umbraco projects. Below are some common options.
Have you tried the Skybrud Redirects package? With this package, you can easily create redirects to content and media within your Umbraco installation or to external URLs (which is your case as far as I see).
You can install the package using this command which will create a new Redirects section in your Umbraco backoffice from which you can create/update/delete your redirect rules.
dotnet add package Skybrud.Umbraco.Redirects --version 4.0.17



Another option is that you can create a simple document type (no properties should also be fine for your case) and an empty template, create a new content page using this document type and template, and do a redirect to your external URL in your RenderController of your content page (Response.Redirect).
Here is a nice blog article that follows this approach and some sample code for redirects. https://swimburger.net/blog/umbraco/crawling-through-umbraco-with-robots
public class TestRedirectPageController : RenderController
{

    // Removed for brevity 
    
    public override IActionResult Index()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 301;
        return Redirect("https://www.google.com/");

        //return base.Index();
    }
}

Your final option can be Umbraco's custom routing feature. You can find the documentation here: https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/implementation/custom-routing

Thanks for your comment. I have added more details to my answer to make it clearer.
